# Where is HasDefaultSchema in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm porting my EF to EF Core.  There doesn't appear to be a **HasDefaultSchema** method in the new API.  What is the equivalent of this code EF Core?

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Notifications");
  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's [exactly the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalmodelbuilderextensions.hasdefaultschema?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalModelBuilderExtensions_HasDefaultSchema_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ModelBuilder_System_String_) as the sample code.

The only difference with EF6 is that as most of the EF Core fluent (and not only) method it's implemented as extension method (rather than instance method) of the `ModelBuilder` class inside the [`RelationalModelBuilderExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalmodelbuilderextensions?view=efcore-2.1) class.

In order to use it, make sure you reference the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/), and have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I needed to add the Microsoft.EntityFramework.Relational package.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: Net Core 5.0

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using SQL Server as the Database, so in this case I had to

1. Install both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` packages, and,
2. Include `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Note, only installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` will complain that 'HasDefaultSchema ' is undefined, and also VS would not provide any suggestion to install the other package.