# .NET Code First is adding user login as default table schema

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am having a strange behavior when I apply a migration to my online db with Entity Framework Core. All of the tables take by default the UserId defined in my connectionstring as the default schema. I know how to change it but I'd like to understand the reason why this is happening. Notice that it does not happen with a local database, the schema remains as "dbo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default schema for the User using:

```
ALTER USER myUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA [myschema]
```

So you can set your user to have the default schema of `dbo`, if you wish.

I'm guessing dbo is already set as the default schema for the user that you connect with locally.

You can also specify the default schema in Entity Framework Core. See this question: [Where is HasDefaultSchema in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310255/where-is-hasdefaultschema-in-entity-framework-core)

Note that it is a good practice to use a different user for applying your migrations than what you use for querying etc.